# VariableSizeWrapGrid: remove item when started to drag it

Tags: windows-8, drag-and-drop, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, variablesizedwrapgrid

I have a VariableSizeWrapGrid and custom drag/drop handling logic. I need to remove (or collapse) the item when it began being dragged. VariableSizeWrapGrid's dataSource is ObservableCollection.

Collapsing (`Visibility=Collapsed`) an item does not work: it becomes invisible, but occupies its original space anyway. Invalidating VariableSizeWrapGrid does not get rid of these spaces.

Removing an item does not work because dragging process is aborted by some unknown reasons when i'm removing **dragged item** from its original source. Removing any other items does not abort dragging. I've overridden `void OnItemsChanged(object e)` with empty handler (not calling base version), but this does not help too.

Short code sample:

```
void VariableGridView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{
    var tile = e.Items[0] as Tile;
    tile.removeFromOwnerContainer(); // this line interrupts dragging
}
```

Comment: What does `removeFromOwnerContainer()` do? Does it remove the tile from the ObservableCollection? Or does it attempt to remove it from the `ItemContainer`?

Comment: `removeFromOwnerContainer()` removes an item from its ObservableCollection

Comment: I've implemented custom simple drag&drop logic to workaround this behavior. However, i'd like to get an answer to original question.